# How to create a dynamic worksheet based on dimesion selector

Tags: tableau-api

I want to create a worksheet that simply display no. of people in terms of gender and no. of people in terms of city . I don't want to create two worksheets(one for gender and another for city) .

At first ,i want to create a drop down that lists two values such as "gender", "city"

If "gender" is selected from that drop down then no. of people in terms of gender needs to be displayed

Similarly, if "city" is selected from that drop down then no. of people in terms of city needs to be displayed.

Lets say below is the input

```
----------------------------------------------------
id      name    gender    city
----------------------------------------------------
100     Sam       MALE      CHENNAI
101     Mike      MALE      CHENNAI
102     Tammy     FEMALE    MUMBAI
103     Rick      MALE      MUMBAI
104     Eric      MALE      MUMBAI
105     Stev      MALE      MUMBAI
106     Betsy     FEMALE    CHENNAI
```

I am able to create a two separate views , one for gender and one for city ..

But I don't know how to have only one view that gets changed as per selection from a drop down .

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use a parameter. See the sample attached workbook. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/160322%20stack%20question.twbx

For more information on parameters, check out this link http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/parameterized-measure